elasticsearch: Unable to connect to the remote server
I am trying to test if Elasticsearch is running by running curl http://localhost:9200/
I get the error:
curl : Unable to connect to the remote server
I have searched for similar posted problems but the solution did not work for me. The suggested solution is around setting the network.host and http.host in elasticsearch.yml  to 0.0.0.0. I have tried that but I still encounter the issue.
Here is how parameters are set on my elasticsearch.yml
network.host: 0.0.0.0
http.host: 0.0.0.0
http.port: 9200
transport.host: 0.0.0.0

What other approach should I try out?

did http://0.0.0.0:9200/ works ?

@Mathew curl http://0.0.0.0:9200/ returned the same error

I found out what was missing. I was able to sort out the issue by starting Elasticsearch as a service
elasticsearch-service.bat start
